# convert object to CSV string without header Servicestack CSVSerializer

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm using Servicestack.text CSV serializer to serialize an object into CSV format. Here is the way Im trying

```
CsvSerializer.SerializeToString(MyObject)
```

But it converts into CSV including the headers like this

ID,Name, Age\r\n13,Alex,45

But I dont need those headers. Is there is any way to exclude the header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can omit headers for being written per `Type` with:

```
CsvConfig<MyType>.OmitHeaders = true;
```